# Embed from TXT file, then add class selectively

Tags: jquery

Here is the gist. First I need to embed a TXT file into the webpage. Then I need to scan the newly embeded links and selectively apply a CSS class.

I have each of these aspects working separately, but not together. And I’m stumped as how to achieve this without the use of PHP.

---

**JQuery**

```
// embed the content
// only works on a webserver, not locally
$(".portfolio_all_listed").load("embed-me.txt");

// add the current page marker
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('currently_viewing');
    }
});
});
```

---

**HTML**

```
<ul class="portfolio_all_listed">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the complete callback of `load`

```
$(".portfolio_all_listed").load("embed-me.txt", function(){
    // new html now exists ,  `this` is target of the load
    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('currently_viewing');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for your help!